Parameter in calibration are not sufficient for pruposed Model. Where is the lacking data coming from?
The paper „social security reforms, capital accumulation and welfare: A notional defined contribution system vs a modified payg system“ by Lin, li
Presents a model for analyzing the impact of switching from a PAYG system to a modified PAYG system and notional defined system in China.
I want to apply the model to my homecountry. In the paper they calibrate some key variables, but not all of them (at least in my understanding)
Now im wondering where they got them from, since its not explained how they are calculated.
I assume these variables might be explained by some of the calibrated parameters, but I don’t get how.
Specifically am talking about A_t * w_t. Where A_t is the productivity parameter and w_t the rate of return on affective capital, so A_t * w_t represents the rate of return to Labour.
Does anyone have an how to get those values the way they did in the paper?
It you’ll be very appreciated.
I can also provide all necessary Formulars and definitions if needed.
Thanks in advance:)

Why is your title so different from the body of your question? There is no failure of calibration, you are asking for data that they did not get via calibration. Can you please edit the title?
